# Unable to interpret '|' character

Tags: swift, swift2, autolayout

I need your help because I dont understand what's going on with my auto constraints. The constraints of my switch make the app crash. When I remove them it work nicely.
This is the error message that I get:
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|-100-[v0(35)]|

thx for your help

Here is my code :

```
class selectionCustomCell: UITableViewCell{
    var label: UILabel = {
        let attribution = UILabel()
        attribution.text = "Nom du label"
        attribution.textColor = UIColor(r: 0, g: 185, b: 255)
        attribution.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        attribution.numberOfLines = 0
        attribution.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return attribution
    }()

  var switchElement: UISwitch{
        let sL = UISwitch()
        sL.setOn(true, animated: true)
        sL.onTintColor = UIColor(r: 0, g: 185, b: 255)
        sL.tintColor = UIColor(r: 0, g: 185, b: 255)
        sL.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sL
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(switchElement)
        addSubview(label)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews(){
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": label]))          
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[v0]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": label]))


        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-100-[v0(35)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": switchElement]))


        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[v0(35)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": switchElement]))


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the difference between how `label` and `switchView` are declared: `label` is initialized to the output of a closure, which is executed the first time it is referenced.  `switchView` is a calculated property with a getter that is invoked each time it is referenced, which means that the versions you are referencing in `-setupViews` aren't the same as the one that you called `-addSubview` on previously.  Since they don't belong to a view hierarchy, the visual format is invalid.

If you make the declaration of `switchView` match the declaration of `label`, your code should work as expected:

```
var switchElement: UISwitch = { // note the assignment operator here
    let sL = UISwitch()
    // ...
    return sL
}() // note the invocation of the block here
```

Comment: Wow, SUCH a simple difference, you just saved me hours, thank you!